# insert sequential numbers into a string using regex/grep/sed/awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

Does anyone know how use regex/grep/sed/awk to insert sequential numbers into a string? I have a long `.xhtml` document (using BBEdit to edit) with lots of plain `<p>` tags, and I want to transform them to `<p id="0001">`, `<p id="0002">`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I do. If you have a followup question see [ask] and don't forget the [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

#### Sample xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</root>
```

#### Code demo

```
c=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -c 'count(//p)' file.xml)                                                                  
for ((i=1; i<=$c; i++)); do                                                                                      
    xmlstarlet edit --inplace --insert "//p[$i]" --type attr -n 'id' -v $(printf '%04d' $i) file.xml
done
```

#### Sample Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <p id="0001"/>
  <p id="0002"/>
  <p id="0003"/>
</root>
```

#### Note

This is a bit hacky, even if itWorks©®™,  a better solution would be to use a language like [python](/questions/tagged/python), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) with a *XML parser*. It's not *that* difficult

Comment: Updated answer with use of `xmlstarlet`

Answer (score 0):

In awk, using @Gilles Quenot's example:

```
$ awk '/<p>/ {gsub(/<p>/,"<p id=\""sprintf("%04d",++i)"\">")} 1' example.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <p id="0001"></p>
  <p id="0002"></p>
  <p id="0003"></p>
</root>
```

Explained:

```
/<p>/ {             # if <p> in record, replace it, sprintf for zeropading i
    gsub(/<p>/,"<p id=\""sprintf("%04d",++i)"\">")
} 1                 # print
```